# How do I bind a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to the list property of the parent row's bound object?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Given the following classes:

```
public class Shirt
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Color> ColorOptions { get; set; }
    public int SelectedColorId { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Why can't I get the combobox to show up in the DataGridView using the following code?

```
        List<Shirt> foundShirts = _dbShirtRepo.GetShirts();

        var nameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        nameColumn.DataPropertyName = "Description";
        nameColumn.HeaderText = "Description";

        var colorSelectColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        colorSelectColumn.DataPropertyName = "ColorOptions";
        colorSelectColumn.DisplayMember = "Label";
        colorSelectColumn.ValueMember = "Id";


        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colorSelectColumn);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = foundShirts;
```

Comment: when you use the debugger what are the values in `foundShirts` when you step thru the code before assigning the datagridview1.DataSource also state if this is a `winforms app or a webforms app`

Comment: WinForms. foundShirts does in fact contain a list of Shirt objects.

Comment: I get the following error after I assign the datagridview1.DataSource:

The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:

System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

... for each Shirt in the list.

Comment: My solution:

After I bind the DataSource to the entire DataGridView. I just iterate through the DataGridView.Rows collection, grab the combo box column and explicitly add items to the DataGridViewComboBoxCell based on a property of the object bound to the row. Hope that help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo = this.dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        combo.DataSource = ((Shirt)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).ColorOptions;
    }
}
```

As you can see, you have to provide `DataSource` *per request* because you can only have one at a time. There's no way to pre-set different data sources for each combo in each row.

You can improve the above solution but the concept is the same:

- User clicks, hovers or otherwise "activates" the cell
- Set up the `DataSource` of the column's combo before user has a chance to open it

This way user is not aware of any shenanigans going on and you can offer different choice for every individual row.

**Note:** I'm not 100% sure of how `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` operates, it's entirely possible that it caches and persists its data sources but experiment a bit before relying on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the `DataSource` property for the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. There are different ways to solve your problem.

Set the `DataSource` of the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to `foundShirts.ColorOptions`. With this you get to see only colors available in the `foundShirts` list.

```
var colorSelectColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
colorSelectColumn.DataPropertyName = "ColorOptions";
colorSelectColumn.DisplayMember = "Label";
colorSelectColumn.ValueMember = "Id";
colorSelectColumn.DataSource = foundShirts.ColorOptions;
```

If you want to see all the possible colors you could have, prepare a separate list of all possible colors and set it as the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` `DataSource`.

```
List<Color> allAvailableColorOptions = new List<Color>();
// add all the possible colors to this list.

var colorSelectColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(); 
colorSelectColumn.DataPropertyName = "ColorOptions";   
colorSelectColumn.DisplayMember = "Label";
colorSelectColumn.ValueMember = "Id";
colorSelectColumn.DataSource = allAvailableColorOptions;
```